# MySQL Use of Having and Where Clause

Tags: mysql

Having difficulty returning the desired results.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
    DATABASE()AS INVOICES_Range_$0,
    count(
        DISTINCT invoice_lines.invoice_header_id
    )AS 'Invoice Header Count',
    sum(invoice_lines.accounting_total)AS 'Dollar_Value',
    100 * COUNT(
        DISTINCT invoice_lines.invoice_header_id
    )/(
        SELECT
            COUNT(
                DISTINCT invoice_lines.invoice_header_id
            )
        FROM
            invoice_lines
        WHERE
            (
                invoice_lines. STATUS NOT LIKE '%new%'
            )
        AND(
            invoice_lines. STATUS NOT LIKE '%voided%'
        )
    )AS 'Percent of All Invoices',
    COUNT(approvals.approvable_id)/ count(
        DISTINCT invoice_lines.invoice_header_id
    )AS 'AVG_APPROVALS'
FROM
    invoice_lines
LEFT JOIN approvals ON invoice_lines.invoice_header_id = approvals.approvable_id
WHERE
    (
        invoice_lines.accounting_total = 0
    )
AND(
    invoice_lines. STATUS NOT LIKE '%new%'
)
AND(
    invoice_lines. STATUS NOT LIKE '%voided%'
);
```

This query returns results where any invoice line has a value of $0.

For reference, we may have an invoice where one line is $0 but the other lines total $600.

I am wanting to only include in the above query where the total of all the invoice lines equal $0.

I've tried:

```
    SELECT
    DATABASE()AS INVOICES_Range_$0,
    count(
        DISTINCT invoice_lines.invoice_header_id
    )AS 'Invoice Header Count',
    sum(invoice_lines.accounting_total)AS 'Dollar_Value',
    100 * COUNT(
        DISTINCT invoice_lines.invoice_header_id
    )/(
        SELECT
            COUNT(
                DISTINCT invoice_lines.invoice_header_id
            )
        FROM
            invoice_lines
        WHERE
            (
                invoice_lines. STATUS NOT LIKE '%new%'
            )
        AND(
            invoice_lines. STATUS NOT LIKE '%voided%'
        )
    )AS 'Percent of All Invoices',
    COUNT(approvals.approvable_id)/ count(
        DISTINCT invoice_lines.invoice_header_id
    )AS 'AVG_APPROVALS'
FROM
    invoice_lines
LEFT JOIN approvals ON invoice_lines.invoice_header_id = approvals.approvable_id
WHERE
    (
        invoice_lines. STATUS NOT LIKE '%new%'
    )
AND(
    invoice_lines. STATUS NOT LIKE '%voided%'
)
HAVING
    SUM(
        invoice_lines.accounting_total = 0
    );
```

However, that returns the same results. Also, when modified to

```
HAVING (SUM(invoice_lines.accounting_total) < 500 )
```

It returns all invoices and the total amount.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, as I cannot determine the proper method for limiting my results to those invoice_header_id to only count those invoices where the sum of all lines is equal to 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
HAVING
    SUM(
        invoice_lines.accounting_total = 0
    );
```

probably wants to be

```
HAVING
    SUM(
        invoice_lines.accounting_total
    )  = 0
```

Comment: HAVING SUM(invoice_lines.accounting_total) = 0 returned results as if the HAVING statement was not included.

Comment: That would imply all the results are not zero.  Are there very small float values that are not revealed due to output precision or something?  You could try multiplying by 100 and casting to int before checking for 0, at least to test the idea.  Otherwise the correction I showed is the way you get what you want (assuming no bugs in MySQL).

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to evaluate in the WHERE clause using the 'Dollar Value' identified earlier in the query.

I changed the SUM(invoice_lines.accounting_total) as TOTAL

and then in the WHERE clause I added AND (TOTAL = 0);

Worked like a champ.